# Failed to execute goal org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.5.3:build (javacpp-cppbuild-compile) on project libnd4j:

Tags: java, maven, deep-learning, deeplearning4j, javacpp

I downloaded the repository from https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j. From the directory, I executed `mvn clean install`. After a while I got this error :

> ````sh
> Failed to execute goal org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.5.3:build (javacpp-cppbuild-compile) on project libnd4j: Execution javacpp-cppbuild-compile of goal org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.5.3:build failed: Process exited with an error: 1 ```
> ````

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You don't provide enough information to answer your question here, re run maven with the trace option as the error message suggests, and re-post your question or edit this one.

Comment: If you do not need to build from source, consider using the snapshots: https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/config/config-snapshots

Comment: @SamuelAudet Thanks ! Building from source was not required !!